# How can I add missing avatar/profile pictures in Messages?

Tags: macos, messages

In the new Messages application introduced with Mountain Lion, I cannot see my own avatar.

This is happening even though my `Messages.app` email is linked with my contact in `Contacts.app`.

No Avatar appears when I text in Messages:

[image]
[image]

But I do have an avatar in Contacts:

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can set your own avatar, one that is even different from the one in your address book with the following menu selection:

*Messages → Change my Picture...*

Comment: Unfortunately Apple decided to do it this way. This means when changing the Avatar of "My Card" in AddressBook, it remains the old one.... Do you know a fix for that?

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a bug but as a workaround you can set the avatar by using the Buddies window:

1. open Window > Buddies
2. click the avatar box at the top right to select an image or just drag & drop an image on this avatar box

Apparently, the Buddies window shows up only if you have a "classic" IM account setup too, like GTalk or AIM.

Comment: I don't see the menu option *Buddies* under *Window*. In fact, I haven't found the menu entry Buddies anywhere - the search comes up with no results. Just other options like "sort buddies" or "show offline buddies". However, while searching for *buddies* I found another entry which was the solution to my problem. Thanks anyway!

Comment: yeah, just tested a bit and updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

I guess the contact picture on your contacts is from Facebook? If so, Messages does not seem to see it. The picture has the be "set" in the Contacts.app, not imported through Facebook (or Twitter, I guess).

Comment: The contact picture I have was set in the contacts app. But Messages was not able to use it. Hence my original question.